# Execute multiple jQuery effects on the same element in parallel

Tags: jquery

I see that this question was asked many times, but none of the solutions worked for me.
I have two effects that I want to execute in parallel.

I want the box to fade-in and bounce simultaneously:
http://jsfiddle.net/6VVUG/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Chain the UI effects, and use `dequeue()` to execute them all at once.

```
$("#t").hide().show("fade", {},  {duration:1200}).effect("bounce", { times:3 },  { duration:400}).dequeue();
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/6VVUG/1/)

Comment: Thanks! You can either chain or put the dequeue() on the last effect: http://jsfiddle.net/6VVUG/2/ 
What is interesting that if you put dequeue() on both effects, the animation brakes.

Comment: Yes, thats right, adding animations onto the same element is exactly the same as chaining them, they get added to the FX queue, and dequeue plays them all at once, emptying the FX queue, so if you use dequeue at the end of each statement, it won't work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function g()
 {
    $("#t").hide();
    $('#t').show();
    $("#t").animate({ opacity: 0.5 }, 0).effect("bounce", { times:3 },  { duration:400, queue: false});
    $("#t").animate({ opacity: 1 }, 0);
 }
```