# Is there a way creating a slide down bounce effect?

Tags: jquery, slide, effect, bounce

I want to create an div, which slides down, when the page is loaded with a bounce-effect.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#viewport').slideDown({duration: 1000, easing: method, complete: callback});
});
```

I think, I am really close to the solution or not.

Thank you in anticipation!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This requires JqueryUI, and then is done by choosing your easing method from any of the functions listed.

http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/

Here's a snippet from my bouncy easing:

```
$("#methods").slideToggle(700,"easeOutBounce");
```

Answer (score 0):

check  out this thread
[Execute multiple jQuery effects on the same element in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473572/execute-multiple-jquery-effects-on-the-same-element-in-parallel)